# Using a function as Callback of another one declared with namespaces

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WordPress Sage Starter theme (https://roots.io/sage/). It uses namespaces for function declarations.

I have a function (my_function_comments) in my lib/extras.php file to modify the comments markup. This file has this namespace: namespace Roots\Sage\Extras; 
Now I need to use that function as a callback in another file templates/comments.php as this:

```
<?php wp_list_comments(array('style' => 'ol', 
                          'short_ping' => true,
                          'avatar_size' => 60,
                          'type' => 'comment',
                          'callback' => 'my_function_comments',
                          )); ?>
```

Of course, my_function_comments is not on this file so I've coded the call to wp_list_comments like this:

```
<?php use Roots\Sage\Extras; ?>
<?php wp_list_comments(array('style' => 'ol', 
                          'short_ping' => true,
                          'avatar_size' => 60,
                          'type' => 'comment',
                          'callback' => 'Extras\my_function_comments',
                          )); ?>
```

Ok, the callback function as this is obviouslly wrong, but I don't know how to write it to call it properly.

Maybe someone can help me to figure out this.

Thank you!

PS. Namespaces related documentation is found here (Namespaces section): https://roots.io/upping-php-requirements-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/. Maybe that will help a bit to answer my question.

Comment: Functions has nothing to do with namespace declarations, only classes (and their methods). If you `include`d the file where the function is, and if it's in global scope, then it is accessible. But if it's a method, then you should see its accessibility attributes (if static, then `Extras\Class::my_function_comments`. If not, `Extras\Class->my_function_comments`)

Comment: Use the full namespace in the callback (inside the string). The namespace is required when wordpress executes the callback, not when you declare it. You can omit the line with ‘use‘.

Comment: Thank you both!! I'll try and post the solution. Thank you!

Comment: The function was not in a class, but in a file with a namespace. @WeSee option solved my problem. I'll post a solution for everyone to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Wesee said in the comments, the way to use the function as a callback is putting the whole path to the function. So then I removed this line:

```
<?php use Roots\Sage\Extras; ?>
```

And use this to call wp_list_comments:

```
<?php wp_list_comments(array('style' => 'ol', 
                      'short_ping' => true,
                      'avatar_size' => 60,
                      'type' => 'comment',
                      'callback' => 'Roots\Sage\Extras\my_function_comments',
                      )); ?>
```

Thank you guys!